# print an image without its title

Tags: drupal-7

I would like to take an image field without printing its title. In this way that I'm using, print the field title and below the image:

```
$view = field_view_field('node', $node, 'field_immagine_std');
print render($view);
```

Answer (score 1):

I found this solution:

```
 print render($content['field_immagine_std'][0]);
```